# Module not found error in Visual Studio Code despite the fact that I have just installed it

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, cherrypy, modulenotfounderror, path-variables

I want to run a python script with the cherrypy module. I use `pip install cherrypy` to install it and all looks ok. Then I click the "Run python file" button and I face the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cherrypy'`.

Trying to reinstall cherrypy I see many `Requirement already satisfied` responses.

If it helps I have already edit, in the user path variables panel, the Path variable and added `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts` as a path.

edit: I suspect some problem with the path. So i run the following.

```
>>> import os
>>> import sys
>>> os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
'C:\\Python25'
```

it returns: `'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0'`

Comment: Something must be a typo because according to your current edit, you've got **3 different versions of Python**: 2.5, 3.7 and 3.9. Even it's 2.5 is actually 3.5 that's still 3 versions. It's also like that the first `pip` in the path for `pip install ...` isn't for the same version of Python which is first in the path. Clean up your system or use **full-paths** when excuting pip and python.

Comment: And maybe [install Python from the official site](https://www.python.org/downloads/) instead of the Microsoft Store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to install `cherrypy` using `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\pip install cherrypy`

When I install py libraries I always run `where python` and find the right python copy it and modify the path so it goes in `Scripts` then run `pip install cherrypy`

Also I noticed that when I install py libraries it seems VSCode won't recognize it even though it runs. To fix this you have to restart VSCode again

Another possibility is that your VSCode isn't using correct version of Python. To check this look at VSCode bottom left you should see your python version. If VSCode can't recognize it you will have to enter the Python path manually by Open Command Palette `Ctrl+Shift+P` and choose `Python: Select Interpreter` then `click enter Interpreter path`

Comment: I just did and it says "Requirement already satisfied". I have tried multiple times to restart VSCode.

Comment: At the bottom either left or right there should be little button that allow you to select your python version. Have you checked that?

Comment: Oh that was it. I was using the 3.9 python. How can I make it install there and not in the 3.7 one?

Comment: Open Command Palette(Ctrl+Shift+P) and choose `Python: Select Interpreter` then click `enter Interpreter path` and paste in your python 3.7 path

Comment: If that solved I'll update my answer